# Break for loop after x number of inputs

Tags: c++, loops

So I'm Trying to get the code to stop when the user passes the guess limit of 10
At the moment its a endless loop unless loop that only stops when the user gets the correct number. Any fixes to break the loop when the user reaches their guess limit

```
int main(){

    srand(time(NULL));
    int randomNum = rand()%50;


    int usr_in, guessLimit = 10;


    for(usr_in = 0; usr_in != guessLimit; ++usr_in)
    {
        cout<<"Enter a number between 0 & 50: ";
        cin >> usr_in;

        if(usr_in == randomNum)
        {
            cout<< "Correct guess you win"<< endl;
            break;
        }
        if(usr_in < randomNum)
        {
            cout<<"Guess higher"<<endl;
        }
        if(usr_in > randomNum)
        {
            cout<< "Guess lower"<<endl;
        }
   }
   if(usr_in == guessLimit)
    {
        cout<<"You lose"<<endl;

    }
}
```

Comment: You use `usr_in` as both the loop counter *and* the user input. It can't be both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overriding `user_in` variable.

In this line: `cin >> usr_in;`, so you don't remember previous value.

Please remember to return value, if function has return type.

```
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int randomNum = rand() % 50;
    const int guessLimit = 10;
    int usr_in;
    for(int guess = 0; guess < guessLimit; ++guess)
    {
        cout<<"Enter a number between 0 & 50: ";
        cin >> usr_in;

        if(usr_in == randomNum)
        {
            break;
        }
        else if(usr_in < randomNum)
        {
            cout<<"Guess higher"<<endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout<< "Guess lower"<<endl;
        }
    }
    if(usr_in == randomNum)
    {
        cout<< "Correct guess you win"<< endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"You lose"<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```